# What is the container that Roy is carrying to the Lima Project shuttle?

Tags: ad-astra

In sci-fi drama *Ad Astra* (2019), Roy carries a container to the Lima Project shuttle with him.

[image: inside of a shuttle, character in space suit holding a light grey metallic container]

What is that container?

Comment: A [plot-armour](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlotArmor) generator, I expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a nuclear weapon. Brad Pitt's character takes it with him to his father's ship, then

> detonates it at the end of the film.

You see it being retrieved from a container marked with nuclear symbols at timestamp *1:16:11*

> "I remain fully committed to the completion of the mission, namely to destroy the Lima Project in its entirety"
>
> [image: GIF showing a person in protective gear opening a container marked with nuclear warning symbols]