# What switch did Roy turn on?

Tags: ad-astra

In sci-fi drama *Ad Astra* (2019), before he comes out of the Lima Project shuttle with his 
father, Roy turn on some switch on his spacesuit:

> AUTOMATED VOICE: Armed. T-minus three hours.

What switch did Roy turn on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's arming the (cylindrical) nuclear weapon [that we saw in the previous scene](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/228050/20774).

[image: picture of the weapon]

Apparently the top comes off so you can get at the gizmo inside.